Chrome extension: How to modify the cookie header in response (& request) headers in a network call in manifest v3?
I want to add tab ID as prefix in the Cookie response header of a web request before it reaches the web application and similarly want to remove that prefix from the Cookie request header before the web request leaves browser (for server).
I see that rules in the declarativeNetRequest API doesn't support setting dynamic (runtime) values for a header. Also, the webRequestBlocking is removed for manifest v3.
How can I do that in my manifest v3 extension?
Here is my v2 implementation:
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  (details) => {
    const { tabId, responseHeaders } = details;
    responseHeaders.forEach((responseHeader) => {
      if (
        responseHeader.name.toLowerCase() === 'set-cookie'
      ) {
        responseHeader.value = `${tabId}_${responseHeader.value}`;
      }
    });
    return { responseHeaders };
  },
  { urls: allowedURLs },
  [
    'blocking',
    'responseHeaders',
    chrome.webRequest.OnBeforeSendHeadersOptions.EXTRA_HEADERS
  ].filter(Boolean)
);


I'm not sure of the timing when the header must be present/removed, so it'd be helpful if you elaborate or show your existing MV2 code. Either way, the only MV3 method for an extension that wasn't installed via policies is declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules which must be called before the request is made. Depending on the timing and the overall workflow there may be a way to do it reliably.

@woxxom I have added my v2 implementation above. I am not sure how can I do it using updateSessionRules and how should the rule be.

I don't see any workaround. Report this case in https://crbug.com and in WECG.
